# How do I export a kubernetes manifest file without the metadata?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, devops, amazon-eks

I'm trying to export a daemonset from my kubernetes cluster but I dont want any of the metadata. Is there a way I can export the manifest file without the metadata, like `creationtimestamp`, `uid_selflink`, etc.

for example, something like this would be perfect:

```
kubectl get daemonset mydaemonset --no-meta-data -o yaml > exported-mydaemonset.yaml
```

I want to discard information about the current object state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the annotation field `kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration`, which holds the resource initial applied configuration without auto-generated fields.

Get it manually, or parse it with [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq):

```
kubectl get daemonset mydaemonset -o yaml | \
yq r - 'metadata.annotations."kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration"'
```

Comment: Hi Eduardo, your suggestion helped me in my research on how to remove this metadata. I eventually used a combination of your script and jsonpath to remove the unwanted metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do
`kubectl apply view-last-applied daemonset mydaemonset -o yaml` which gives you the output in the format you require.